# how to show/hide a div with many children(> 7000) without style recalculation

Tags: html, performance

This is an Android app that uses WebView to display a long list. The long list's visibility can be toggled by the following JS function:

```
function _showOverlay() {
    $("#container").css("visibility", "visible");
}

function _hideOverlay() {
    $("#container").css("visibility", "hidden");
}
```

a style recalculation is triggered by both function. On desktop the performance is fine but on slower phone device (Galaxy Nexus class), the performance is not acceptable.  Anyway to speed this operation up? or, any other trick I can use to show/hide a div?

Tried the following:

1. "opacity:0" - can't use this because the list can still respond to user touches while invisible (bad)
2. "display:none" - triggers same style recalculation.

Comment: You mean you have more than 7000 elements in wherever website that is?

Comment: Please show the code you did

Comment: Without seeing the code, my only offering is that perhaps you're better off hiding the parent container and not the children and splitting containers so that the repaint time is divided.